# Vertically align middle for all elements in div

Tags: html, css

I am coding the header of my webpage.
But I found that the elements(sometimes image, sometimes textfield) inside my div did not align vertically.
I tried to use vertical-align: middle and line-height but fail to do the job.

http://jsfiddle.net/v68jpypz/1/

```
#free-wifi {
    line-height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`vertical-align: middle` only works when the element is marked as a `table-cell`, so do it like this:

```
#free-wifi {
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/xv6mthv5/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/v68jpypz/7/

```
.right {
    float: right;
    display:table;
}

#social-network {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

You can do the same for the left div.